# Continuous spectrum of an integral operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

I understand that the continuous spectrum of an operator are the $\lambda's$ such that $(\lambda-T)$ is injective but ran$(\lambda-T)$ isn't dense in the image. But i can't properly calculate it for a given example. For example consider the operator $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ such that $$Tf(x)=xf(x)+\int_0^xf(\xi)\:d\xi$$
I was able to determine the point spectrum of this operator, but what shall one do in order to find its continuous spectrum?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

$$
   Tf = xf(x)+\int_0^xf(u)du, \;\; f\in C[0,1]. 
$$
The resolvent operator is $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$, assuming the operator inverse exists and is bounded on $C[0,1]$. $g=(T-\lambda I)^{-1}f$ is a function such that
$$
           (x-\lambda)g(x)+\int_0^xg(u)du = f(x) \\
       (x-\lambda)\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xg(u)du+\int_0^xg(u)du=f(x) \\
     \frac{d}{dx}\left[(x-\lambda)\int_0^xg(u)du\right]=f(x) \\
     (x-\lambda)\int_0^xg(u)du=\int_0^xf(u)du \\
      \int_0^xg(u)du = \frac{1}{x-\lambda}\int_0^xf(u)du \\
        g(x)=-\frac{1}{(x-\lambda)^2}\int_0^xf(u)du+\frac{1}{x-\lambda}f(x)
$$
Therefore,
$$
    (T-\lambda I)^{-1}f=-\frac{1}{(x-\lambda)^2}\int_0^xf(u)du+\frac{1}{x-\lambda}f(x)
$$
This is well-defined for a given $\lambda$ if, for all $f\in C[0,1]$, the right side of the above is in $C[0,1]$. So $\sigma(T)=[0,1]$.

Comment: Nice trick, though in my mind it is easier to think of $T=S+K$ with $S$ Fredholm and $K$ compact, and then $\sigma_{ess}(T)=\sigma_{ess}(S)=[0,1]$). But, how does this address the continuous spectrum?

Comment: Hi @MartinArgerami : It's not really a trick. It's a direct construction of the resolvent operator.

Comment: I consoder noticing that $T-\lambda I$ is a derivative, a "nice trick". Without it, it is not hard to find the expression for the resolvent, but it is less elegant because first one needs to assume differentiability, and only a posteriori notice that the formula for the resolvent works everywhere.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : I definitely take your statement as a nice compliment, coming from a Professor of Mathematics. By the way, your link on the about me section of this website is out-of-date. This is one I found for you: https://www.uregina.ca/science/mathstat/faculty-staff/faculty/argerami-martin.html . I wish the IT staff wouldn't do things like that to people. :)

Comment: Our IT staff is fine, I don't have complaints :D  That said, the link does work for me, and it opens the same page you are linking to. Weird.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Perhaps the link you are using on this site can only be resolved from within the University. I would encourage you to change the link so that everyone can access the page. Or you could ask IT what link to use.

Answer (score 1):

The continuous spectrum is empty.

Fix $\lambda\in\sigma(T)$. From DisintegratingByParts' answer we know that $\lambda\in[0,1]$. We also know that
$$\tag1
(T-\lambda I)f(x)=\frac d{dx}\Big[(x-\lambda)\int_0^xf\Big].
$$
So if $g\in\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)$ then
$$
g(x)=\frac d{dx}\Big[(x-\lambda)\int_0^xf\Big].
$$
We can write this as
$$
\int_0^x g=(x-\lambda)\,\int_0^x f.
$$
In particular, this forces
$$\tag2
\int_0^\lambda g=0.$$
Considering the real part,
$$\tag3
\int_0^\lambda \operatorname{Re}g=0.
$$
This implies that there exists $s\in[0,1]$ with $\operatorname{Re}g(s)=0$. Then
$$
\|1-g\|_\infty\geq|1-g(s)|\geq|1-\operatorname{Re}g(s)|=|1-0|=1.
$$
So $\operatorname{ran}(T-\lambda I)$ is not dense, which implies that $\lambda\not\in\sigma_c(T)$. As $\sigma_p(T)=\emptyset$, this shows that
$$
\sigma(T)=\sigma_r(T)=[0,1]. 
$$

---

**Edit: $T-\lambda I$ is injective.**

Let $\lambda\in[0,1]$. Suppose that $(T-\lambda I)f=0$. By $(1)$ above this means that there exists a constant $c$ such that
$$
(x-\lambda)\int_0^xf=c.
$$
Taking $x=\lambda$ we see that $c=0$. So, for any $x\ne\lambda$, we have that $\int_0^xf=0$. Taking the derivative we get that $f(x)=0$ with the possible exception of $x=\lambda$, but we get $f(\lambda)=0$ by continuity. So $T-\lambda I$ is injective.

Comment: Could you please clarify why you used $||1-g||_\infty$ to evaluate the density?

Comment: Furthermore, why is $g(\lambda)=0$? Isn't it equal to $\int_0^\lambda f(x)\:dx$ ?

Comment: My bad. I tried to make it shorter and skipped an essential part. As for $\|1-g\|$, "dense range" means that any element has elements from the range arbitrarily close.

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you for your answer.  I believed i proved that the operator (\lambda-T) can't be injective for $\lambda\in[0,1]$ which would imply that both the continuous spectrum and the residual spectrum are empty, so actually the point spectrum would represent all the spectrum, Which goes in contradiction with your claim. Are you sure that the point spectrum is empty?

Comment: I don't know how you found eigenvectors, but I have included my argument that $T-\lambda I$ is injective. If you see something wrong, let me know please.